# Daemon OWASP ZAP on Azure App Service always returns code 400 - Bad Request

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, zap

I am trying to run a daemon instance of OWASP ZAP to use ZAP API on an Azure App Service - Container.

Configuring the image as `owasp/zap2docker-stable` and indicating the startup command

```
zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config api.disablekey=true
```

I get to run in the App Service the following docker command (taken from the logs)

```
docker run -d --expose=8080 --name zap-tool_8_4bedc839 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=zap-tool -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=zap-*****.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=b9972c7b5014a11146e04035fe1b8e55b22384befd7977a509e8dc0b******** -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e NODE_OPTIONS=--require /agents/node/build/src/Loader.js -e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar -e StartupBootstrapper=Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StartupBootstrapper -e DOTNET_SHARED_STORE=/agents/core/store/lin -e DOTNET_ADDITIONAL_DEPS=/agents/core/additionalDeps -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config api.disablekey=true
```

After loading the script in the logs I find the message saying the server is listening, but at the first call (a dummy call that the app service makes) we get a `bad request` response, and like that all the following requests made (even a GET server root)

```
2023-01-19T09:47:17.840154581Z 105098 [ZAP-daemon] INFO  org.zaproxy.addon.network.ExtensionNetwork - ZAP is now listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599466935Z 106791 [ZAP-IO-Server-1-1] WARN  org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API - Bad request to API endpoint [/robots933456.txt] from [169.254.130.1]:
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599494735Z org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.ApiException: bad_format
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599499835Z  at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:438) ~[zap-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599504035Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.handlers.ZapApiHandler.handleApiRequest(ZapApiHandler.java:100) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599518235Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.handlers.ZapApiHandler.handleRequest(ZapApiHandler.java:74) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599529835Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.handlers.ZapApiHandler.handleMessage(ZapApiHandler.java:59) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599533235Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.notifyMessageHandlers(MainServerHandler.java:147) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599536335Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.processMessage(MainServerHandler.java:129) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599539435Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.LocalServerHandler.processMessage(LocalServerHandler.java:66) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599542435Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.process(MainServerHandler.java:94) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599545535Z  at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(MainServerHandler.java:82) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599548535Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599551535Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599554535Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599557635Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599560535Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.Format.ROBOTS933456.TXT
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599563635Z  at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240) ~[?:?]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599566535Z  at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API$Format.valueOf(API.java:62) ~[zap-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599569635Z  at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:417) ~[zap-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
2023-01-19T09:47:19.599572636Z  ... 12 more
```

What could cause this error ? What could cause the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.Format.ROBOTS933456.TXT` ?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you (or something, at least) has made an invalid request to the ZAPI API:

> Bad request to API endpoint [/robots933456.txt]

Either dont make a request like that or ignore the errror :)

FYI it is probably easier to control ZAP using the [Automation Framework](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/) instead of via the API.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, error 400 and bad request has a clear meaning, but launching the same exact command to spawn the docker image worked just fine in local, while on app service we get error 400 even requesting the root (where plain HTML should be returned). API were chosen because the aim was to request scans chosen by websites team to validate a new site before releasing it